# Clicking Facebook 'Like' Button (iFrame) throws Error

Tags: facebook, wordpress, console

When clicking on the Facebook 'Like' button on my page (WordPress blog, single entry page)

my console shows the error:

```
NetworkError: 500  - https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like/connect?__a=1
```

I've debugged the page with the Facebook Object Debugger, and have eliminated any errors. I'm racking my brain and can't figure out what the issue is.

If it helps, When clicking the like button again to remove the like, the console shows:

```
NetworkError: 500  - https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like/disconnect?__a=1
```

I see there are a lot of people having issues with Facebook. Could this be related?